# Can I implement a classifier using a function?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I was learning about different techniques for classification, like probablistic classifiers etc , and stubled upon the question Why cant we implement a binary classifier as a Regression function of all the attributes and classify on the basis of the output of the function , say if the output is less than a certain value it belongs to class A , else in class B . Is there any limitation to this method compared to probablistic approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this and it is often done in practice, for example in [Logistic Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). It is not even limited to binary classes. There is no inherent limitation compared to a probabilistic approach, although you should keep in mind that both are fundamentally different approaches and hard to compare.

Comment: I was doing some googling and found out probably i'm talking about a predictor vs classifier comparison . So you mean they are same predictors are continous while classifiers are more of a discrete type ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There's really no difference between a predictor and classifier at this level. It is true that some models have a discrete set of possible outputs while others can predict continuous values. For classification, you would discretize the output in the latter case and end up with essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding in classification. No matter what kind of classifier you are using (svm, or logistic regression), you can always view the output model as
    f(x)>b ===> positive
    f(x) negative

This applies to both probabilistic model and non-probabilistic model. In fact, this is something related to risk minimization which results the cut-off branch naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. For example, a [perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) does exactly that.

However, it is limited in its use to [linearly separable problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability). But multiple of them can be combined to solve arbitrarily complex problems in general [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network).

Another machine learning technique, [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), works in a similar way. It first transforms the input data into some high dimensional space and then separates it via a linear function.